# INDESIGN: Replace column break with paragraph return

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I am using Adobe Indesign.  I want to replace all the column breaks (numberpad enter) with paragraph returns without having to do each and every one.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I've tried using the find/change feature, but I haven't found anywhere in there that I can easily search for a column break and paragraph return.

Answer (score 0):

Just use GREP and appropiate metacharacters

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that would work if it didn't keep crashing. :( Thank you, though.

Comment: Loic, this is not a *programming-related question*. As your answer shows.